# apache: rewrite js remove timestamp

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

well, i would like to rewrites js:

```
/resources/js/general.js/1234/ -> /resources/js/general.js
```

due to akamai's cache i can't use regular querystring: **?t=1234**

static works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js/[0-9]+/$ /resources/js/general.js [NC,L]
```

but i can't build a dynamic regex :(

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js/[0-9]+/$ $1 [NC,L]
```

results in:

```
/resources/js/general
```

well, but:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js/[0-9]+/$ $1.js [NC,L]
```

results in:

```
/resources/js/general.js/1234/
```

and:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js/[0-9]+/$ $1\.js [NC,L]
```

results in:

```
/resources/js/general.js/1234/
```

thank you :)

edit with all .htaccess:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
Options +Includes
XBitHack on
RewriteEngine on

# works static
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js/[0-9]+/$ /resources/js/general.js [NC,L]
# not dynamic
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js/[0-9]+/$ $1.js [NC,L]
```

Comment: it redirect's to: `http://domain/home/projects/proyectName/public_html/resources/js/general.js` i don't need a redirect, i a rewrite need show de js's content

Comment: edited the post with .htacces but is the only one

Comment: i would like to rewrite "/resources/js/general.js/1234/" in "/resources/js/general.js" for example

Comment: yes... the .htaccess is working, if you read the main post the "static" mode works fine but i need to change it to be for general purpose, with any js

Comment: ok try this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.+?\.js)/[0-9]+/?$ /$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: works, please put it as response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rewrite rule by this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.js)/\d+/?$ /$1 [NC,L]
```